# Отловить изменение времени андроид приложением

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver

Как определить изменение времени приложением? BroadcastReciever работает только когда приложение активно либо в фоне. Есть какие-либо варианты?

Comment: `BroadcastReciever` Работает, пока он зарегистрирован. Его можно регистрировать в сервисе, например, если вам нужно ловить события также когда приложение закрыто